# phonegap build error plugin is not on npm: Device

Tags: phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am  using phonegap-version cli-5.2.0 i could not build apk. error is here below 
Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: Device

**my config.xml** 
this is my config file my plugins are given below
org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation,Device,Logger,Compass,NetworkStatus,Debug Console,Geolocation,SplashScreen,Battery,Globalization

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"  id = "com.test.www" version="1.1" >
    <name>test</name>    
    <description>
       test
    </description>
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" />           
    <feature name="Geolocation">
         <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <plugins>
            <plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
            <plugin name="Logger" value="CDVLogger" />
            <plugin name="Compass" value="CDVLocation" />
            <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
            <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
            <plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
            <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
            <plugin name="Battery" value="CDVBattery" />
            <plugin name="Globalization" value="CDVGlobalization" />

    </plugins>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />


  <!--<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />-->
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />

    <icon src="images/ldpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="images/mdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="images/hdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="images/xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <!-- iPhone icons -->
    <icon src="images/57.png"  gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="images/114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />


    <icon src="images/72.png"  gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="images/76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="images/120.png"  gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="images/152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />


    <!-- Android splashes -->
    <gap:splash src="images/sldpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/smdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/shdpi.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/sxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <!-- iPhone splashes -->
    <gap:splash src="images/320x480.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="images/640x960.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="images/640x1136.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"  />

  <gap:plugin name="com.devexpress.plugins.devextremeaddon" version="1.0.1" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.li8.inappbrowser" version="0.1" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics" version="0.6.1" />

  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="3.8.1" />

  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="foo" />

   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" />

  <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: You have mistakes in your `config.xml`. Please post

Comment: i include my config.xml file

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this, but it has MANY errors. This will take about 20 minutes to fix. READ: [http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html#The%20Basics) If you are on a laptop the right side has the documentation index.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've fixed up your `config.xml`, but you likely have errors in your index.html also. I would suggest you post that as well.

Also, i removed the icons, plugins, preferences, and more, because you can always add those back. This example gets you working.

You should read the [Phonegap Build blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/) for the last 60 days or so, and there are more changes coming in the next 30 days. If you get a chance skim through the [Cordova blog](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/) as well.

You should also skim this: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
AND READ these

- [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
- [Core Plugins Setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md)

Glossary - [deprecated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprecated#Adjective)  means - *considered old, and planned to be phased out, but still available for use.*

### Your Fixes

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Read: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"  id = "com.appbogoo.www" version="1.1" >
    <name>BOGOO</name>    
    <description>
       BOGOO
    </description>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"    source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"   source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"   source="npm" spec="2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar"      source="npm" spec="1.0.0" />

    <!-- No longer available -->
    <!-- <gap:plugin name="com.devexpress.plugins.devextremeaddon" version="1.0.1" /> -->
    <!-- Deprecated -->
    <!-- <gap:plugin name="com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics" version="0.6.1" /> -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics source="npm" spec="0.8.1" />
    <!-- Deprecated -->
    <!-- <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="3.8.1" /> -->
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing source="npm" spec="5.0.7" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Plugin name and value is the package name of plugin. example:

```
</description>
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" />           
<feature name="Geolocation">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
<plugins>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />

        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" value="CDVConnection" />
        <plugin name="Debug Console" value="CDVDebugConsole" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" value="CDVLocation" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
      //etc...

</plugins>
```

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.

Comment: Change Plugin name and value is the package name of plugin.  example :  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />