# Error on building this app on phonegap build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile-application, phonegap

[image: ***Error image***]This is my XML page, this app is built using PhoneGap, When I try to build on PhoneGap (android) it shows this error, Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependency of this plugin is not on NPM: com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar.

```
  <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
          xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" 
          id="EG7ZTZQ3JQ.com.klystrontech.LemonPR" version="1.0.0">
  <name>Lemon PR</name>
  <description>Lemon PR app for event booking</description>
  <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">Klystrontech Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>

  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="splashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />

  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />

  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm"/>

  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"/>
  <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"/>
 <icon src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" 
  gap:qualifier="xhdpi"/>
 <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry"/>
 <icon src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" 
   height="57"/>
   <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" 
    height="72"/>
    <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" 
  width="114" height="114"/>
 <icon src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" 
    height="144"/>
 <icon src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" gap:platform="webos"/>
     <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" 
     gap:platform="winphone"/>
      <icon src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" 
        gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background"/>

  <splash src="splash.png"/>



       <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" 
   gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
   <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" 
    gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" 
      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
      <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" 
   gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>
      <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" 
    gap:platform="blackberry"/>
      <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" 
   gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
  <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" 
   gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
      <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h2x.png" 
     gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
     <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" 
     gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
     <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" 
     gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
     <gap:splash src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" 
     gap:platform="winphone"/>
     <access origin="*"/>
     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
     <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
     <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
     <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
     <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
     <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
     <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
        <platform name="android">
       <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
      </platform>
      <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
      </platform>
     </widget>
```

Please help me solve this problem, is it due to the plugins properly not installed?

Comment: did you installed `com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar` plugin inside your project?

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931728/phonegap-build-error-plugin-is-not-on-npm-device

Comment: @AkhileshPatil yes, is it like this, cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj any update ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugins>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
.......
</plugins>
```

Add a plugins tag and add your all 3rd party plugins, like above

Comment: No change, Same error when trying to build this app.. !

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj can you pls change the plugin name to package name `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`